# nodemon watch directory for changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I know how to do `nodemon server.js` but what if I want to do `nodemon ./src`

I want restart node on any changes in the directory of `src`.

When I do above and it say `cannot find module babelprac\src`

I am also doing in another command window : `npm run scripts:watch`

The script is

```
"scripts" : {
  "scripts" : "babel src --source-maps-inline --out-dir dist",
  "scripts:watch" : "babel src --watch --source-map-inline --out-dir dist"
},
```

That runs the watch but I want to run the script in src or dist to see the console.logs

I aslo tried `nodemon --watch ./src`. It says it can't find index.js.

I am on windows 7

My working directory is `babelprac`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Nodemon expects it just as:

`nodemon --watch src server.js`

https://github.com/remy/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories

> nodemon --watch app --watch libs app/server.js

Comment: It say at the begining of the doc `nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started` if I use server.js it seems to me like it will watch server.js not the directory. I want it to watch the directory.

Comment: and `--watch app` signature  doesn't work for me. I read that page before asking this question.

Comment: @jackblank No, you are telling nodemon the script to run which is `server.js`. That line means that nodemon will watch all files and directories where you run `nodemon server.js` from, which is where you are starting nodemon.

Comment: @jackblank Did you try `nodemon --watch src server.js` you have to replace `--watch DIR` with the directory you would like to be watched for changes, app is an example.

Comment: I tried
`C:\Users\jack\Desktop\practice\stackPrac\jsPrac\babelprac>nodemon --watch src main.js`

Comment: It says `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\practice\stackPrac\jsPrac\babel
prac\main.js'` For some reason it doesn't recognize src directory now. I have it in babelprac.

Comment: @jackblank does the file `main.js` exist? You need to put the nodeJS script you want to run there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133495/discussion-between-kody-and-jack-blank).

Comment: watchexec -w src -e purs -- spago

Answer (score 77):

**Nodemon** also has a more fine-grained approach for watching folders and files. Use `nodemon.json` to specify what files and the types of files to watch, as below in your case:

```
{
  "watch": ["server.js", "src/"],
  "ext": "js, css"
}
```

Having a `nodemon.json` is particularly useful when the number and types of watched files start to bloat, and also when you want to run a script upon each server restart. For **nodemon** to read in the configuration, `nodemon.json` should be placed at the root directory of your project, along with every other hidden and not hidden json files.

Below is a good place to start your `nodemon.json`.

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md

Answer (score 25):

I use this for hot replacement, nodemon `--watch` src and run `tsc` complier.

you can also check this article:
https://medium.com/netscape/start-building-web-apps-with-koajs-and-typescript-366264dec608

```
"scripts": {
  "watch-server": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec 'ts-node' ./src/server.ts"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !

Official doc says   , we can't use * ;  but the  *  is effective in my practice  : )

Comment: Whatever I do, nodemon is only working for a single file but not folder, I am unable to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me. In the first create a file name nodemon.json in the home directory of your project and then add this

```
 {
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "execMap": {
    "js": "node --harmony"
  },
  "events": {
    "restart": "osascript -e 'display notification \"App restarted due to:\n'$FILENAME'\" with title \"nodemon\"'"
  },
  "watch": [
    "test/fixtures/",
    "test/samples/"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js,json"
}
```

you can add your directory name in the "watch" option to be monitored by the nodemon for any changes and add your files type in the "ext" option

Answer (score -3):

Install it:

npm install npm-watch

"scripts":

```
"watch": "npm-watch"
```

Comment: The question was explicitly about `nodemon` so this answer does not help. Your answer also lacks an explanation how the `npm-watch` package would be used to achieve what @op wants to achieve.