# How to enable hot reloading for the build folder in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, dotnet-cli

I have a React application created using `create-react-app`. I also have an external application that is using this application by including the bundled `JS` and `CSS` files (the ones create using the `build` script).

Right now, I'm using the React template created by the `dotnet new` command, and I have configured the server to serve static files located in the `build` folder.

For this reason, I have created a couple of additional NPM scripts that rename the bundle files (remove the hash from the name), so that I don't need to update my external application's links with every build.

Right now, whenever I change something in the code, the whole build process has to be processed to create the two files.

I have created a "watch" task to run my build scripts whenever I have a change, but I was wondering if there is a way to speed up the process and somehow configure the React application to be served from memory or something just like when we "normally" run the application.

So, maybe a couple of questions:

1. How to achieve this in a "normal" React app created by `create-react-app`?
2. how to achieve this in the context of the `dotnet` template?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nodemon` in the `build` folder of the create react app.

as the documentation says

> By default nodemon monitors the current working directory. If you want to take control of that option, use the --watch option to add specific paths:

so you can use something like this:

```
nodemon --watch app --watch libs app/server.js
```

for details try other approaches given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729664/nodemon-watch-directory-for-changes)

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to your **filesystem, file extensions or the Create-React-App default webpack/project** configuration. You don't necessarily have to change all of this because hot-reloading is supposed to work out of the box, and more so if the project has just started.

For example, I once had an issue with a Typescript installation(^17.0.1) where some files with extension .ts will not trigger hot reloading. I had to change to .tsx and add a React import. The same could happen with .js and .jsx files.

In case of problems with your filesystem (Unix, Mac) you can try the React config **(FAST_REFRESH=false)** [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)... or changing folder names, but I haven't bumped much into this.